# How do you install a package to a directory?

Tags: debian, apt, software-installation, directory

I am a Debian user. Configuring different servers using Debian distro.

I am trying to install packages that locate into my /usr/ directory.

How do you install packages to the `/usr/` directory?

**I performed the following command -**

```
# sudo apt-get install [package name]
```

I performed the `whereis [package]` command,

Any package I install just goes to the `/etc/` directory.

Comment: I don't think your `whereis` output is telling you what you think it is, but you could [edit] in a few concrete examples and someone could see.

Comment: try dpkg and see https://askubuntu.com/questions/129022/determine-destination-location-of-apt-get-install-package

Comment: What is the output of `whereis -l`?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think that this is feasible. A package does not have a single location on the filesystem.
When a debian package is created, the developer specifies what files go where. Later, during the actual installation, the files are placed in their desired locations.

FYI:

- you can list all your packages with `dpkg -l` (no root).
- you can than check the content and the location with `dpkg -L <package-name>` (no root).

Comment: I was trying to set up a samba server, but samba's instructions has the directory of /usr/local/samba/ but when I installed it its installed at /etc/samba/ so I was just wondering if there was a way of installing samba to /usr/ or is /etc/samba/ is that only location to install samba to

Comment: A package like samba will install things all over the place, `/etc` for configuration, `/usr` for application/administration code, and `/lib/modules/{kernel}/fs` for the filesystem driver.